# Adding UIButton to UIView Results in White Text

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

A `ViewController` in a project written in Swift 5 renders `UIButtons` improperly. When I add a UIButton programmatically to the UIView, it shows up with white text instead of the normal iOS blue.

Here is the code showing exactly how I am adding the button to the view:

```
let goButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: 60, height: 60))
goButton.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
designerView.addSubview(goButton)
```

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

In the screenshot I set the background to transparent to show the issue, since when white, the one added programmatically wouldn't show.

I don't have any global styles or extensions for buttons. I have tried to remove the UIViewController and UIView, and then re-add them, but that didn't resolve what I am experiencing.

Is this an issue of a setting on my storyboard? Do I manually need to set the values by calling `setTitleColor`? Shouldn't the buttons the same whether I add them via the storyboard or if I manually add them by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is from how you create the button. You should use the `init(type:)` initializer, then set the frame.

```
let goButton = UIButton(type: .system)
goButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 60, width: 60, height: 60)
goButton.setTitle("Go", for: .normal)
```

This gives the expected blue button text.

Setting the `type` to `.custom` also gives white text which is what you get by default using the `init(frame:)` initializer.

Comment: I thought I was missing an init call somewhere. Thanks for pointing that out!